# Questions about email reverse DNS check

Tags: email, smtp

Our email server was blocked, I need find a way to solve this.
About the outbound SMTP IP, when I send emails from my email server, if I send them to a SMTP relay on my other server, which IP the receive side will check for the reverse DNS? the email server IP or the relay server IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiving mail server will do a reverse dns check on the mail server that it received the message from.  So, if your mail server sends a message through a relaying mail server, which then sends the message to the receiving mail server, the receiving mail server will do a reverse dns check on the relaying mail server.

The reverse DNS check works like so:  Say the receiving mail server receives an incoming connection from 209.85.160.179.  The receiving mail server will do a reverse DNS lookup on this IP, which (in this case) will resolve to mail-yk0-f179.google.com.  To confirm that the sending mail server is in fact in the google.com domain (and 209.85.160.179 is not run by a spammer or spoofer who simply setup a PTR record for 209.85.160.179 that points to mail-yk0-f179.google.com), the receiving mail server then does a forward DNS lookup on mail-yk0-f179.google.com, to make sure that this FQDN does in fact resolve to 209.85.160.179 (a spammer would not be able to setup a DNS record for a FQDN in google.com's domain).

So, legitimate senders should have a PTR record setup for the IP address that their mail server sends from, and the FQDN that the PTR record points to should resolve back to this same IP.  This is how spam filters identify mail from home computers that have been taken over by bots or zombies for sending spam - as most IPs used for home internet connections will not pass a reverse DNS check.